# How to determine roots of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-numbers

Let us consider an equation  $x^3+10x^2-100x+1729=0$. Will this equation have at least one complex root having modulus $>12$?

Comment: solve it, then inspect your roots if their modulus > 12 or not

Comment: @learningmaths, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690033/show-that-the-equation-x310x2-100x1729-0-has-at-least-one-complex-root-z

Comment: How do you know that one root will be complex@labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 0):

Trying to plot it [in an online free tool](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/) gave this result
[image]

I can see that the function crosses x-axis only once around $x = -19.5$, does that help you ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is roots of your equation . As you can see modulus of the complex roots are less that 12 .